# why shallow copy is working different for nested list elements and non nested list elements?

Tags: python, shallow-copy

Why shallow copy working in different for nested list elements and non nested list elements? I don't understand why it is doing like this.

It is doing shallow copy function is working in two different ways:

1. for non-nested list elements working as deep copy
2. for nested list elements working as shallow copy.

here I am providing the code for that.
please give me clarity on this. with graphics possibly.

```
lst_1 = [1,2,[3,4],5]

lst_2 = lst_1.copy()

lst_1[2][0] = 'Now'

lst_2[0]='haha'

print(lst_1)

print(lst_2)
```

output is:

```
[1, 2, ['Now', 4], 5]

['haha', 2, ['Now', 4], 5]
```

Comment: "A [shallow copy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) constructs a new compound object and then (to the extent possible) inserts **references** into it to the objects found in the original." Therefore, `lst_2`'s elements are references to the same `1`, `2`, `[3,4]`, and `5` as `lst_1`. So `lst_1[2]` is the same reference as `lst_2[2]`.

Comment: 'lst_1 = [1,2,[3,4],5]\

lst_2 = lst_1.copy()\

lst_2[2][0] = 'Now'\

lst_2[0]='haha'\

print(lst_1)\

print(lst_2)'\  **changes in lst_2[2][0] affecting list_1[2][0] but change in list_2[0] not affecting in list_1[0]. If the references are copied then why not changing in list_1.

Comment: After the copy, `list_2[0]` and `list_1[0]` are both references to the number 1. After `list2_[0] = 'haha'`, `list_2[0]` is now a reference to `'haha'`. This has no effect on `list_1[0]`. `list_1[0]` is still a reference to the number 1.